# Rails & Heroku - Find User By Lowercase Username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

in rails development environment I find a user by its lowercased username in the routes.

For example:

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id].downcase)
```

This piece of code runs perfectly fine in development, but when this code runs in production (Heroku) I get

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass):

Is there a go around for this issue?

Comment: "Is there a go around for this issue?" - here's a question. Do you know what the issue __is__? I feel particularly bored right now, so I can ask hinting questions until you figure it all out.  :)

Comment: The user isn't found so are you sure it's in the db on the production server?

Comment: Did yo try: `User.where("name = ?", params[:id].downcase)`?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla Yes I've tried this and it seems like this is being caused by case sensitive parameters. If I pass "localhost:3000/Username" in development it will find the user even if it's "Username" or "username" I'm guessing find_by_username(params[:id].downcase) doesn't work in postgres?

Comment: @Hipady is your params[:id] actually the username? or the id? it would depend on how you are submitting. I would assume if you are trying to find_by_username you would have something like find_by_username(params[:username]) not with params[:id].

Showing more of your code might help us more.

Comment: @ConorFischer is rigth, maybe the problem is in the value of params

Comment: I've found the solution, and it wasn't wrong because of wrong values. As I've answered my own question, `User.where('lower(username) = ?', params[:id]).first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the end I've used

```
User.where('lower(username) = ?', params[:id]).first
```

Sorry for the consfusion and the incertitude :)

Comment: good for you! don't forget to add an index on `LOWER(username)`.